# Image not updating on repaint

Tags: java, image, japplet

So the file image.png is getting overwritten every 2 seconds. I want an applet to display the image in a browser. It does display the image, but the problem is the image never gets updated in the applet after the image file was updated on the computer. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class ImageUpdate extends JApplet {  

  Image picture;  
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  int delay = 2000; //2 second
  int period = 4000; //4 seconds

  public void init() {  
    picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"image.png");  

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {

             repaint();

              System.out.println("image updated");
          }
        }, delay, period);      
  }  

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawImage(picture, 0,0, this);     
    }        

  public void update(Graphics g) 
  { 
      super.paint(g);

  } 
}
```

Comment: your image would have already been loaded into the applet on the `init` method. Place `picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"image.png");` inside the `TimerTask.run` method.

Comment: 1- Make sure you clear the `Graphics` context before you perform custom painting; 2- You've not reloaded the image in any way, so how is it suppose to know that it's changed.  The original is loaded into memory to speed up access

Comment: @ ug_ picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"image.png"); in timertask did not work.

Comment: @magprogrammer I think you are right, but not finding a way to clear it. any code examples?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why not simply use HTML/JS for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up on the applet, and did it in html and JavaScript. It works so much better this way. Thanks Andrew. I had really wanted to get the applet to work, but ... whatever.

```
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
  function refreshIt() {
    if (!document.images) return;
      var date = new Date();
    document.images['image'].src = 'http://localhost:8080/image.jpg?ts=' + date.getTime();
      setTimeout('refreshIt()',2000); // refresh every 2000ms
 }
  //--></script>
</head>

<body onLoad=" setTimeout('refreshIt()',2000)">

<img src="http://localhost:8080/image.jpg" name="image">

</body>

</html>
```